Open Source LLM Repeating Tokens Until Max Tokens Reached - How to Fix?
I'm working with an open-source language model (LLM) for generating text in Portuguese, and I'm encountering an issue where the model keeps repeating tokens until the maximum number of tokens is reached. Here's a snippet of my code:
# Import necessary libraries
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, TextStreamer, BitsAndBytesConfig
import torch

# Set up 4-bit quantization configuration
bnb_4bit_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True
)

# Load the model with 4-bit quantization
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "rhaymison/Mistral-portuguese-luana-7b-chat",
    quantization_config=bnb_4bit_config,
    device_map={"": 0}
)

# Load the tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("rhaymison/Mistral-portuguese-luana-7b-chat")

# Set the model to evaluation mode
model.eval()

# Define the input prompt
prompt = """<s>[INST] Qual o seu nome?
[/INST]"""

# Tokenize the input
inputs = tokenizer([prompt], return_tensors="pt").to(model.device)

# Set up the text streamer
streamer = TextStreamer(tokenizer, skip_prompt=False, skip_special_tokens=False)

# Generate the response with adjusted parameters
generation_config = {
    'max_new_tokens': 128,
    'temperature': 0.7,       # Increase temperature for more randomness
    'top_p': 0.9,             # Use top-p sampling
    # 'repetition_penalty': 1.2, # Apply repetition penalty (Adding a repetition penalty gets rid of the repetition but still generates gibberish until it reaches the max token limit.)
    'eos_token_id': tokenizer.eos_token_id, # Set eos_token_id
    'pad_token_id': tokenizer.pad_token_id  # Set pad_token_id
}

# Generate the response
_ = model.generate(**inputs, streamer=streamer, **generation_config)


Despite setting the temperature and top_p, the model keeps generating repetitive tokens until it hits the max token limit. I have already tried setting the eos_token_id and pad_token_id, but the problem persists. I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing in the configuration or if there are other parameters I should tweak. By adding a repetition penalty, I managed to eliminate the repetition, but it still generates a bunch of changing emojis until the max token limit is reached.

Hi, I have tested the model and can't reproduce your error. Does the problem exist on a specific prompt?

However model prompt to output a lot of smiles at the end of it's answers...

Sorry, I forgot to mention that while trying to solve the error, I added a repetition penalty, which did eliminate the repetition. However, the model then substituted the repetition with a series of changing emojis that are generated until the max_tokens limit is reached. I have updated my question with this information.
